# Microchip PIC24FJ SPI writes correctly but only reads zeros

Tags: c, pic, spi

I have a PIC24FJ256GA702 communicating with a AD5724RBREZ quad DAC with a SPI link.
The DAC works fine, writing is no problem, but I am stuck on reading back the control register from it.
I get the correct waveform on the PIC pin that I am expecting, and the read routine runs, but it always returns zeros. The waveform is clearly not zero- the waveform on the scope is correct for the 4 channels and the internal reference being enabled.
[Scope view of waveforms - blue = clock, yellow = data input from DAC at PIC pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66HaM.png)
(The excessive ringing on the scope image is probably caused by a long distance ground connection- in practice these chips are about 25mm apart.)

I thought that the input pin was configured as an analogue, but it was correctly a digital input.
I connected it to a counter based on Timer1, and that counter does count if I try to read the DAC. This suggests that the PPS is working, the pin is not bust, and the the input signal is clean enough to use.

I think it may be a problem with the code or the decode timing of the SPI module, but as shown in the image the data is stable during the clock cycle so I cannot see what is wrong.

I have searched the forums, and it seems most with this problem trace it to analogue functions being enabled but that is not the case here.

Would anyone like to suggest something else to try, or post some working SPI read code if my code is not looking correct?

The code follows-

```
void AOUT_init(void)
{
    //assume PPS is unlocked (it is on reset) - see note below
    
    //setup SPI1 itself
    SPI1CON1L   =   0x0160;     //TX work read 0
    //SPI1CON1L   =   0x0060;   //TX not work
    //SPI1CON1L   =   0x0120;   //TX work, read 0
    //SPI1CON1L   =   0x0020;   //not tried
    
    SPI1CON1H   =   0x3000;
    SPI1CON2L   =   0x0017;     //word length (17 hex = 24 bits)
    //BRG
    SPI1BRGL    =   0x0000;     //default = no divisor
    //PPS - assume unlocked at this point
    ANSBbits.ANSB13 = 0; 
    TRISBbits.TRISB13 = TRIS_INPUT;
    //##########################################################################
    RPINR20bits.SDI1R = 13;     //set SDI1 data input to PIC to RB13    
    //##########################################################################
    
    TRISBbits.TRISB15 = TRIS_OUTPUT;
    RPOR7bits.RP15R = 8;        //RB15 to SDI1 clock out from PIC
    TRISBbits.TRISB14 = TRIS_OUTPUT;    
    RPOR7bits.RP14R = 7;        //RB14 to SDI1 data out from PIC
    //AD5724R has additional lines - not all used in practice
    //setup and set initial level here
    //AOUT-/LDAC
    TRISBbits.TRISB6 = TRIS_OUTPUT;
    LATBbits.LATB6 = 1;
    //AOUT-/SYNC
    TRISBbits.TRISB7 = TRIS_OUTPUT;
    LATBbits.LATB7 = 1;
    //AOUT-/CLR
    TRISBbits.TRISB12 = TRIS_OUTPUT;
    LATBbits.LATB12 = 1;

    //turn SPI on
    SPI1CON1Lbits.SPIEN = 1;
    SPI1CON1Lbits.MSTEN = 1; //included in definition above 
    
    //now setup the AD chip
    //output range set
    AOUT_TX(0x0C00,0x0100); //all channels to 10V
    //control
    AOUT_TX(0x1900,0x0500);
    //power control - enable DACs
    AOUT_TX(0x1000,0x1F00); 
}
```

The comms routine below is included for completeness- it just controls the other DAC lines. The /SYNC line is doing a chip select function.

```
static void AOUT_Comms(bool bSync, bool bLDAC, bool bClr)
{
    //AOUT-/LDAC
    LATBbits.LATB6 = bLDAC;
    //AOUT-/SYNC
    LATBbits.LATB7 = bSync;
    //AOUT-/CLR
    LATBbits.LATB12 = bClr;
            
}
```

This is write routine which works fine.

```
void AOUT_TX(uint16_t dataH, uint16_t dataL)
{
    //AOUT uses 24 bit data
    //this routine handles /SYNC line
    //relies on AD chip having much faster response than chip cycle time 
    //AD chip limits at about 38MHz so much quicker than PIC.
    AOUT_Comms(0,1,1);
    SPI1BUFL = dataL; 
    SPI1BUFH = dataH;
    while(SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY) //wait until sent
    {
        ;
    }
    AOUT_Comms(1,1,1);
    //
     
}
```

This is the read routine, which uses the routines above.

```
void AOUT_read_control(uint16_t ReadH, uint16_t ReadL)
{
    uint16_t temp;
    //to read, transmit the register to be read, then transmit a dummy command "NOP" to clock the data out.
    //send register
    AOUT_TX(0x9000,0x0000);
    //read out- this is similar to write but reads the received buffer at the end.
    //clear buffer
    while (SPI1STATLbits.SPIRBF)
    {
        temp = SPI1BUFL;
        temp = SPI1BUFH;
    }

    
    AOUT_Comms(0,1,1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0; 
    SPI1BUFH = 0x1800; //nop operation via control register
    while(SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY) //wait until sent
    {
        ;
    }
    while (!SPI1STATLbits.SPIRBF)
    {
        ; //hold until something received
    }
    ReadH = SPI1BUFH;
    ReadL = SPI1BUFL;  //these read zero     
  


    AOUT_Comms(1,1,1);
    //
    
    //dummy so can check counter also connected to same pin
    temp = TMR1;
    temp = TMR1;   
    
}
```

Update-
I checked the SPI read decode by sending the received words directly to a  display as suggested by the comments. I get 0000 for both words.
Also as suggested I connected a logic analyser at the PIC pins, and it decodes both read and write correctly.[Logic Analyser view- Ch1/Blue/MOSI writing 0x180000, Ch2/Green/MISP reading 0x00001F, both correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRk51.png)

Comment: Make sure first it's not a hardware issue before analyzing your code, I mean check the `Rx` line first.

Comment: the easiest way for checking hardware is connect  with logic analyzer to see whether output signal is correctly.

Comment: _//these read zero_ - do you see it in the debugger, or you print them from outside the `AOUT_read_control`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments. @AlbertShown - yes, the scope view is from the Rx line at the pin of the PIC, and the counter attached to it shows the signal is changing internally inside the PIC.

Comment: @ThongDT - good point, that would be a good double check and I can look into getting one on there, but the scope waveform looks correct for SPI.

Comment: @user58697 - zero is seen from the debugger inside the routine, and I can double check by porting it to a display on the board (bypassing the debugger) but expect it to be no different.

Comment: Edited question at end to add info - direct display also shows 0000 (no debugger used) and logic analyser on PIC pins show expected read result.

Comment: Maybe you are to late? Try to remove this `while(SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY) //wait until sent`loop

Comment: @REPuzzle If you see it in a debugger (I assume the breakpoint was at the `AOUT_Comms(1,1,1);` line), there is no need to double-check. Just keep in mind that `void AOUT_read_control(uint16_t ReadH, uint16_t ReadL)` signature is plain wrong: you cannot observe the readings from the outside. It shall take pointers, not integers, as in  `void AOUT_read_control(uint16_t * ReadH, uint16_t * ReadL)`

Comment: Thanks for the info- I removed the line as suggested by Mike, but the same result. Yes, the debugger was inside the routine. Good point about the signature, I am used to other languages where you can return multiple values like that but c does not work like that.

Comment: Following on, I put a direct link to the board display inside the routine, and it is showing ReadL as 1. The debugger says it is 0. This is the first time I have got anything other than 0 from ReadL. (Ideally ReadL would be 0x1F.) I double checked on the analyser as it is getting the 0x1F on the pin as before.